# Get URL of active tab in Firefox using recovery.js in profile, using bash, etc

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

The Firefox recovery.js file is one line that always contains the unique string "_closedTabs"; the active URL I need is the first one before "_closedTabs".

Like this: ...{"url":"address"...}...some stuff between..."_closedTabs"...

Strategy:

1. find index of `"_closedTabs"`
2. search for `{"url":` starting with that index, in the **reverse** direction, i.e. to the left
3. get the address part of the URL

No. 2 is the one I'm stumped on.  Searching backwards in a string seems quite a chore; I couldn't find any way to do that.

I know I should use jq, but the 50 MB string is too much for me to find the right places. Getting those two strings directly shouldn't be that hard. Anyone?

I don't have any favorite tools: awk, grep, sed, even plain bash is fine.

**Edit:**

Here's an example string:

`"the-beginning",[{"url":"other-address"}],[{"url":"the-address"}],"the-middle","_closedTabs","the-end"`

1. find index of `"_closedTabs"` << should get index 80
2. from index 80 search backwards to (first) `{"url":` << should get index 44
3. get the address part of the URL

Expected output: `the-address` (without quotes)
If the URL is not found, the output is `No url found`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output. The small snippet of text after `Like this:` currently in your question isn't adequate. Not my downvote btw.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, I couldn't figure out why no-one was taking a shot!

Comment: You're welcome. A good [mcve] would show the target string **in context** among other text, e.g. on a line preceded and/or followed by other text that includes other `{"url":` and/or `"_closedTabs"` instances you need to not be matched. As written you could get an answer that does what you want for the posted string but fails in some instances of your real data.

Comment: I added another url. There's only one "_closedTabs" in the string.

Comment: Is there always just 1 _closedTabs in your whole input? Always just 1 per line? Any cases of _closedTabs without a preceding url:? Any lines without a _closedTabs, etc. Make sure your example is truly representative of the use cases that will occur in your real data.

Comment: I'm working with the recovery.js file, which is in one line. There's only one "_closedTabs". If no {"url": is found that should be the output: No url found.

Comment: Don't assume anyone knows what a "recovery.js" file is (I certainly don't). You said in your question it's one big string, change that to one long line for clarity. Also define "long" as that impacts a potential solution - Kilobytes, Megabytes, GigaBytes, or something else. If you want `No url found` output in some situations then add that and an example that could produce it to your question.

Comment: Do you have or can you get GNU awk? What does `awk --version` output?

Comment: I have gawk --version
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you want, using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='\"_closedTabs\"' '
    RT { sub(/.*\{"url":"/,""); sub(/".*/,""); url=$0 }
    END { print (url=="" ? "No url found" : url) }
' file
the-address
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    (s=index($0,"\"_closedTabs\"")) && match(substr($0,1,s-1),/.*\{"url":/) {
        str = substr($0,RLENGTH+1)
        if ( match(str,/^"[^"]*"/) ) {
            url = substr(str,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
        }
    }
    END { print (url=="" ? "No url found" : url) }
' file
the-address
```

Another way of doing the same thing but just taking it step by step always using `match()` would be:

```
$ awk '
    match($0,/"_closedTabs"/) {
        str = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
        if ( match(str,/.*\{"url":/) ) {
            str = substr(str,RLENGTH+1)
            if ( match(str,/^"[^"]*"/) ) {
                url = substr(str,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
            }
        }
    }
    END { print (url=="" ? "No url found" : url) }
' file
the-address
```

Comment: Could you explain the GNU awk parts? I'm still learning this stuff.

Comment: Not sure what to say about it - is there any particular part you don't understand (after a look at the man page for what `RS`, `RT`, `sub()`, and `END` mean of course)?

Comment: Just what the different lines do? I'll check your gawk in a while and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Please read the man page, it's all very basic stuff and we can't explain fundamentals in every answer.

Comment: Way to go! Your `gawk` solution worked perfectly – got the active tab url. Takes quite a while to run through the 50MB file though. Since the url is almost at the end of the line, I'm thinking of shortening the file. Maybe I should I ask a new question for that?

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Yes, ask a new question about that.